# fgets c standard library function

Tags: c

```
/ * fgets:  get at most n chars from iop * / 

char * fgets(char * s, int n, FILE * iop) 
{ 
    register int c;
    register char * cs; 
    cs = s; 
    while (-n > 0 && (c = getc(iop)) != EOF) 
        if (( * cs++ = c) == ′\n′) 
            break; 
    *cs = ′\0′; 
    return (c == EOF && cs == s) ? NULL : s; 
 }
```

please my question is why cs == s, in the return statement. since fgets is        supposed to return NULL, if end of file, or error occured, why isn't the return   statement just return (c == EOF) ? NULL : s;

getc, is also a c standard library function, that reads a character, at a time from the file iop points to. the function  fgets reads a line from the file iop points to, and returns if successful, the line read, stored in the character array s. returns  NULL, if end of file encountered, or error occured

cheers

Comment: getc, is also a c standard library function, that reads a character, at a time from the file iop points to. the function  fgets reads a line from the file iop points to, and returns if successful, the line read, stored in the character array s. returns  NULL, if end of file encountered, or error occured

Answer (score 2):

> why isn't the return statement just `return (c == EOF) ? NULL : s;`

Because if `cs != s` then obviously some bytes were successfully read before end-of-file or an error was encountered, and it would be clearly wrong for `fgets()` to return `NULL` if it successfully read something before reaching the end of the file.

Comment: this is a line, from progamming in c book(K & R)- Normally fgets returns line; on end of file or error it returns NULL. According to the book, the fgets implementation above, was copied from the standard library

Comment: this is a line, from progamming in c book(K & R)- Normally fgets returns line; on end of file or error it returns NULL.                                    According to the book, the fgets implementation above, was copied from the standard library.                                                                       so if c == EOF && cs != s, s will be returned. But c == EOF

Comment: @user3856947: Yes, that's right. This will happen every time you read the last line of a file, if the last character of the file is not a newline character. In such a case, `fgets()` reads the last line, reaches the end of the file, and then returns the last line. It's how it's supposed to work. If it didn't work this way, you'd never be able to read the last line of such a file. The *next* time `fgets()` is called, presuming the file hasn't been changed, it'll still be at end of file, but now there will be no data to read, so *then* it will return `NULL`.

Comment: Cheers Paul. please one last thing Paul, i will soon be done reading the programming in c book (K & R), and at the moment i am programming console applications. can you refer me to programming in c, in the non-console real life application afterwards. cheers